# При вводе в input с v-model, изменения появляются с отставанием

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Имеются два инпута: 1 с v-model, 2 обычный. При вводе в input с v-model или выборе в checkbox, изменения появляются с отставанием. Без v-model всё быстро, на других страницах такого нет. Подскажите куда копать

```
<b-col cols="3">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Имя файла"/></b-col>
  <b-col cols="3"
    ><b-form-input
      v-model="filename"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Имя файла"
    ></b-form-input
  ></b-col>

  <b-checkbox
    :key="'05:15_A' + idx"
    v-model="selected"
    :native-value="{
    day: n,
    time: '05:15',
    dayc: new Date(year, month, n).getDay(),
    priceId: 1,
    }"
    type="is-success"
    @input="totalPrice">
  </b-checkbox>
```

Через VueDevTools отследил, при вводе происходит event update
[image: VueDevTools]

Input от bootstrap без v-model работает быстро
UPD: Да, дело в чекбоксах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по всему из-за того, что `:key` у b-checkbox связан со значениями, которых нет на скрине я могу предположить что проблема в том, что они изменятся какое-то количество раз что и вызывает иллюзию "задержки", которая по факту является стеком ререндеров.

Comment: Добавил значения чекбоксов, при каждом клике на чекбокс, происходит input, в параметрах каждое уже выбранное значение + новое. Куда тут можно купать?

Comment: В сторону `:key`. Он влияет на рендер компонента к которому применён и если у вас проблема в том, что рендерится не актуальное значение - то, вероятно, она будет связана с `key`.

Comment: Убрал :key у чекбоксов, остались только у ячеек таблицы, логика не поменялась, но "задержка" осталась